# Bootstrap <UL> list -- add an event handler on a large number of list items

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

How can I add an event handler on items of a Bootstrap UL list? The items are added dynamically.

In Bootstrap the UL is:

```
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <ul class="list-group" id="solvedList"></ul>
</div>
```

I add list items dynamically, so there could be easily 50 items on the list.

The list items could be created like this:

```
$.each(list, function(index, solved) {
        $('#solvedList').append('<li><a href="#" class="solvedlix" class="list-group-item" data-identity="' + solved.id+ '">'+ solved.name+'</a></li>');
});
```

After some research I have tried these event handlers.

Attempt 1: (that worked without bootstrap):

```
$('#solvedList a').live('click', function() {
    alert( $(this).data('identity'));
});
```

Attempt 2:

```
$('.solvedlix').click(function(e) {
    var name = e.currentTarget;
    alert( 'Name is ' + name.getAttribute("data-identity"));
});
```

Attempt 3:

```
$("ul li").on("click", function() {
    alert( "In here ...getting access to the sub item later ");
});
```

Comment: [Event Delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read [this](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/). Event Bubbling/Delegation might help so you should give this function a try:

```
$( ".list-group" ).on( "click", "li", function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log( $( this ).text() );
});
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Thank you for the solution and the explanation!